# Generate XSD schema for a complex XML

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

What schema would best suit the following XML

```
<r>
    <a>
        <b>sd</b>
        <c> asd </c>
    </a>
    <a>
        <d> asd </d>
    </a>
    <a>
        <e>sd</e>
    </a>
    <a>lol1</a>
    <a>1.1</a>
</r>
```

Note here that the element "a" may occur any number of times but the structure inside of "a" is varying

---

EDIT:

This might be one way to achieve it:

```
<xs:element name="r">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
        (
          Internal Content
        )
        </xs:choice>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

where, Internal content would contain the schemas of each of the elements named "a" in a sequential order

do comment

Comment: Please add any schema you tried to create to your question, to provide a starting point. You can easily generate a schema using a service like this one: http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html

Comment: This was the schema I settled with
`<xs:element name="r">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
      (
  Internal Content
             )
            </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>`

where, Internal content would contain the schemas of each of the elements named "a" in a sequential order. 

Thanks for the tool though @helderdarocha , used a little help form it :D

Comment: I think you are not finished yet. You can't have several *different* elements named `a` in the same context. Edit your question and include that schema you created, and we can explore some solutions based on it.

Comment: Why do you think that it would not fit any xml?

Comment: You can only *declare one* `a` element per context. You can use `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` to allow many repetitions of *the same type*. Your schema requires that you declare the contents of the complex type of `a` as *mixed content*, and that you either also declare the children that `a` can have, or use `processContents="lax"` or `"skip"`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be one way to achieve it:

`<xs:element name="r">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
            (
              Internal Content
            )
            </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>`

where, Internal content would contain the schemas of each of the elements named "a" in a sequential order